# How do I create an IHTMLDocument2 using a string from TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, html-parsing, indy, ihtmldocument

I download a URL with `IdHTTP.Get`, and I need to search the HTML tags and extract some data.

How I can convert the string that `IdHTTP.Get` returns into an `IHTMLDocument2`?

Comment: thanks but this article used twebbrowser and I wont use webbrowser. because I don't need html rendering I just need HTML text for extracting data, and speed is very important for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Googled this problem and I can find a good code for this:

```
Idoc := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2;
try
  IDoc.designMode := 'on';
  while IDoc.readyState <> 'complete' do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], VarVariant);
  v[0] := MyHTML;
  IDoc.Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
  IDoc.designMode := 'off';
  while IDoc.readyState <> 'complete' do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  ParseHTML(IDoc);
finally
  IDoc := nil;
end;
```

Regards

Comment: What about to use the stream way to load the document ? The `IdHTTP` has the `Get` method overload allowing you to receive response to stream (actually is used in the one returning you the string).

Comment: I would not use that code. all the `designMode` and `Application.ProcessMessages` to check `readyState` is not needed. You don't need to switch to `designMode=on` in order to be able to write to a `IHTMLDocument`. I strongly suggest you use @Keeper's code.

Comment: @kobik, interesting is that this, and even Keeper's code fails on `IHTMLDocument2::write` line with `Invalid argument` on Windows 7, Delphi 7 (Personal) with imported MSHTML type library. The very same happens with `PSafeArray(VarArrayAsPSafeArray(VarArrayOf([HTMLWideString])))`.

Comment: @TLama, I usually declare `document` as `OleVariant` and create it via late binding, e.g.: `document := CreateComObject(CLASS_HTMLDocument) as IDispatch` and simply use `document.write(<WideString>)`. Maybe this is why I never encountered this problem(?)...

Comment: @kobik, it works with type library shipped with Delphi, but doesn't if you import it by yourself (Windows 7). Even more strange is that they're same for `IHTMLDocument2` interface.

Comment: @TLama Why won't this execute javascript? `Doc.Write`

Comment: @TLama Can we chat? :)

Comment: @TLama Its regarding the EmbeddedWB Memory&Handle leaks

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
uses
  ... Variants, MSHTML, ActiveX;

var Cache: string;
    V: OleVariant;
    Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  ...

  Cache := IdHTTP.Get(url);
  Doc := coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2; // create IHTMLDocument2 instance
  V := VarArrayCreate([0,0], varVariant);
  V[0] := Cache;
  Doc.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray)); // write data from IdHTTP

  // Work with Doc
end;
```