# Indy IDHTTP & MSHTML Parse

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create an IHTMLDocument2 using a string from TIdHTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915903/how-do-i-create-an-ihtmldocument2-using-a-string-from-tidhttp)

How can I use MSHTML with Indy to parse the HTML Code that is returned from a website. Or it can only be used with a WebBrowser control? Is MSHTML thread-safe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915903/convert-string-form-idhttp-get-to-ihtmldocument2-in-delphi

Comment: @SirRufo thats it yep.. :)